# Using p:carousel inside p:dataGrid in PrimeFaces 5.3

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid, carousel

Displaying a [`<p:carousel>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/carousel.xhtml) inside a [`<p:dataGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml) using [PrimeFaces 5.3 final](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/primefaces/primefaces/5.3/) (community release) something along the following piece of code.

```
<p:dataGrid var="gridRow" value="#{[1,2,3,4,5]}" columns="1">
    <p:carousel var="row" value="#{[1,2,3,4,5]}" numVisible="3">
        <p:panel>Panel container : #{row}</p:panel>
    </p:carousel>
</p:dataGrid>
```

Using PrimeFaces **5.2** final, it displays the corresponding UI correctly as shown in the following picture.

[image]

Using PrimeFaces **5.3** final, the design is however, severely broken stretching items being held by a `<p:carousel>` too much horizontally as shown in the following picture.

[image]

See the browser's long horizontal scroll bar at the bottom-left corner of the preceding picture.

The problem occurs only when a `<p:carousel>` is displayed inside a `<p:dataGrid>` (or likely other iterating components). A `<p:carousel>` independently displays exactly which it is meant for.

What is the problem with PrimeFaces 5.3? Is there any workaround?

Comment: PF introduces more and more 'responsiveness' into components in new releases. Compare the generated html from both releases, compare the css that is applied, remove the possibly existing custom css and analyze the results. Then you know the cause and maybe create a workaround, or it might just work if custom css was the cause.

Comment: There is no custom CSS at all. Only wrapping the piece of code given inside the basic XHTML format will produce the same without the need to modify the XHTML code given.

Comment: Ok, but then the rest of my comment still stands. And I assume you read the PrimeFaces blog, releasenotes etc from time to time: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3569

Comment: It goes fine when `layout` in `<p:dataGrid>` is set to `grid` (`layout="grid"`). The default value is `tabular`.

Comment: All related to the responsiveness that was added I guess... So 'snafu' ;-)

Comment: The responsiveness approach is clumsy which adjusts contents based on the screen size which is completely undesired in many cases in web applications. Not sure about smart devices like mobile phones.

Comment: Not sure 'device type' is taken into account in the media queries or that you even can (afaik it is always based on screen size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set the `layout` attribute to `grid` in `<p:dataGrid>` (due to the responsiveness feature added to PrimeFaces 5.3). The default value of this attribute is `tabular`.